# Error in .jcall method run with signature not found

Tags: r, rjava

I tried program Geographically Weighted Artificial Neuaral Network (GWANN) and I got error in j.call. This is my script:

```
library(rJava)
r <- .jcall(obj="supervised.nnet.gwann.GWANN_RInterface", method="run", returnSig = "Lsupervised/nnet/gwann/Return_R;",
          
          .jarray(x_train, dispatch=T),
          y_train,
          .jarray(w_train, dispatch=T),
          
          .jarray(x_pred, dispatch=T),
          y_pred,
          .jarray(w_pred,dispatch=T),
          
          norm,nrHidden,batchSize, optimizer, lr, linOut,
          kernel, bandwidth, adaptive,
          bwSearch,
          
          bwMin, bwMax,steps, iterations, patience, folds, repeats, permutations, threads)
```

and console :

> Error in .jcall(obj = "supervised.nnet.gwann.GWANN_RInterface", method = "run",  :
> method run with signature ([[D[D[[D[[D[D[[DZDDLjava/lang/String;DZLjava/lang/String;DZLjava/lang/String;DDDDDDDDD)Lsupervised/nnet/gwann/Return_R; not found

I tried to find what was causing the error in the code but I couldn't solve the error problem.
Do you have any suggestions on how to solve the problem?
Thank you so much in advance. May you have a blessed day